# Let $R$ be integral domain and $F$ a subring of $R$ and also a field then if $\dim_{F}(R)<\infty$ , then $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Because $F$ is a field we can describe $R$ as a verctorspace over $F$, we know that its dimension is $<\infty$ and we also got as a hint to look at the map $\phi:R\rightarrow R,r\mapsto rx$ where $x\notin 0\in R$. How does considering this maps help me to find an inverse for every $x\neq 0$ in $R$ ?

My approach is that if there exists an inverse for every element then those maps must be surjective because since there would be a $r$ such that $rx=1$, we could also describe every other element $z$ in $R$ with this map when we choose as input $zr$, so we have to pove that the map is surjective for any $x$, but how can we do it, and how do we use the dimension property?

We can interpretate the map as a linear map of the same vectorspaces. We could describe the map as matrix and look at the rank, but how do we show that the image of the basis vector is again a basis?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: It is enough to show that $f_r(x)=rx$ is injective since an injective map between finite dimensional vector spaces is surjective.